# SQL Statement inserts double data into MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code to insert data into a table in MYSQL DB for some reason it is inserting the information twice and I require it only to be loaded once

```
<?php
// Record to MySQL
//database settings
$host = "***.***.***.***"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = "*****@"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "gs"; // Database name

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d") ;
$time = date("H:i:s");
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Draw from Form

$imei = $_GET['imei'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO unit_hx SET
                imei = '".$imei."',
                stocked = 'Yes',
                systime = '".$time."',
                branch = 'eTrack',
                status = 'Stock',
                reg = '".$name."',
                notes = 'New Stock Unit',
                sysdate = '".$date."'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO gs_user_objects SET
                imei = '".$imei."',
                sysdate = '".$date."',
                group_id = '0',
                driver_id = '0',
                trailer_id = '0',
                user_id = '247'";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    echo "Updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql1 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
ob_end_flush();
$conn->close();
?>
```

The GET information also only shows as follow

```
new_unit_sql.php?imei=8888888899999&name=T88888
```

Why would it duplicate the insert function on both SQL INSERT strings

test.php basic insert of information

```
<?php
// Record to MySQL
//database settings
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = "b4zre9Trevor74@"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "etrack"; // Database name



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO live_token SET
                reg = 'Test',
                sysdate = 'Date'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); //Retrieve the last ID of the record
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

ob_end_flush();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Even if I prepopulate the SQL without POST or GET it is duplicating

Comment: Use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to check if you perhaps call this script twice. You clearly didn't give us the whole script, so anything is possible. Also, if you care about security and standard practice, see: [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Also, your code is prone to [sql injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is the whole script page the bit I left out is just connecting to the DB section

Comment: `the bit I left out is just connecting to the DB` ... are you sure? `// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);` appears to do that job.

Comment: `Why would it duplicate the insert function`...most likely because this script gets triggered twice. There's nothing _within_ the code provided wihch would cause two inserts. So as the first comment says, look at where you're triggering this script _from_ and monitor it to see if it gets called twice.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited the whole code, The PHP page has nothing else on the page the whole code it there now. I Trigger the page from another pages using the stated URL and GET command

Comment: What kind of answer you expect?

Comment: You say: _"I Trigger the page from another pages using the stated URL and GET command"_. It's probably there where it gets triggered twice. For instance, you use a `<a href="....">` link which does call the script itself, but you've also attached a Javascript click event to it which does also call the script.

Comment: I have created a basic page just to upload data and still for some reason getting duplicate entry. http://e-track.biz/technical/sql/test.php I am not confident with how to see if it is being triggered more than once

Comment: Start adding log statements which log all activity to a log file. Look at the web server's logs. _Any_ indication anywhere that you're receiving two requests where you only expect one…?

Comment: which browser you are using? Did you try other browsers?

Comment: @YourCommonSense so My computer I am programing on and testing from does duplicates from Chrome, If I use another computer's chrome only one record. Cleared cookies and history on my test computer and duplicate so think this is a computer issue not the SQL Script issue, I know I was down voted and I know the code was supposed to work but in a fit of programming the chrome I used was the issue

Comment: Probably some ad-block/prefetch/other sort of extension.

Comment: I agree, it seems to be an extension. Weird. After all this, don't forget the double warning you got about **SQL-injection**.